# Create multiple files from one file

Tags: php

```
foreach($new_files as $new_file) {
    //create file
    $myfile = fopen($filename, "w");

    //put contents in the file                  
    fwrite($filename, $new_file['content']);    

    //close the file
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

I have this code to create a new file, I want to be able to open $filename, and create multiple files from it, with the content of new_file. 
This code doesn't seem to work,all I get is one new empty file, any ideas?

Comment: `$filename` has the same value every iteration of your loop. You need to update that variable to create multiple files.

Comment: I have added a count++ after every file it creates to add a number, but still didnt work.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're wanting to do. You want to copy each $new_file into a _new file_? You want to copy each $new_file into the same file (concatenate the files together? Which is what your code is doing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.

You have to store data in standard structure like JSON in $filename, then read its data and make other files.

```
<?php

// $Data = file_get_contents($filename);
// $Data = json_decode($Data); <--- if stored as json

// Sample Data
$Data = [
    [
        'name'    => 'file1.txt',
        'content' => 'content1',
    ],
    [
        'name'    => 'file2.txt',
        'content' => 'content2',
    ],
];

foreach ($Data as $Row) {
    $File = fopen($Row['name'], 'w');
    fwrite($File, $Row['content']);
    fclose($File);
}
```

Comment: I did it, and I got this warning :Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /script2.php on line 124